# flask --app hello run -- Error: No such option: --app

Tags: python, flask, anaconda

**TL;DR** running `flask --app` from the command line results in `Error: No such option: --app`.

The current version of Anaconda (at the time of this question) includes Flask version 1.x.
Here is the code from the Flask hello world tutorial at: [palletsprojects.com quickstart](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/)

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"
```

and running it with: `flask --app hello run` results in the error,

```
 Error: No such option: --app
```

How can I run this with the "--app" option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Display your flask version with `flask --version`. Using the defaults from the anaconda package manager `condata update flask` won't update flask to 2.x. `--app` works in >=2.2.x. In my case, at the time of this post, `conda search flask` did not show anything past version 2.1.3. To get this version or the latest available,

1. navigate to https://anaconda.org/search?q=flask
2. select the appropriate result for your OS.
3. Use one of the example provided and add your desired version to the end e.g. `conda install -c conda-forge flask=2.2.2`
4. Run `flask --app` and you should get: `Error: Option '--app' requires an argument.`

**Note:** If you're seeing an **Exception: HTTPConnectionPool(...**, make sure you are running these command from an anaconda terminal.